# Getting user location practice in service

Tags: android, service, location

I am once again facing a problem. I am having a alarmManager set up to start a Service which gets user's location every minute. My question is, is this the best practice? To recreate the service every minute, make and register new Location listener and wait for one OnLocationChanged callback ? Or is there a simpler, prettier way of doing it ? Also, don't forged, the screen will be turned off and the device asleep so I need to work with WakeLock too

Answer (score 0):

You can simple start the service once, get a wake lock, and then poll for the location with a time interval of 60 seconds. This will remove the need to recreate the service every time. However, it will be possible for your service to be killed by Android if necessary. You can have it restarted automatically by returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()`.

As a general rule, getting a location every minute is going to be very battery intensive, and should be avoided, especially for long periods of time.